# How to download multiple closing stock prices only with getSymbols into separate xts files?

Tags: r, lapply, quantmod

How can I use getSymbols from the quantmod package to do the following:

1. Download multiple stock price histories
2. Select only the adjusted closing prices--i.e., suppress open/high/low and vol data
3. Save each price history as a separate xts file, with dates

I can implement steps 1 and 2, but I'm having trouble with step 3. StackOverflow has several posts on downloading and merging prices for multiple tickers, but I can't find instructions for downloading and saving in separate files.

Here's what I have so far. Any advice on implementing the last step would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
library(quantmod)
symbols = c("GOOG","MSFT","AAPL")
getSymbols(symbols, from="2011-01-01")
ClosePrices <- lapply(symbols, function(x) Ad(get(x)))
```

I suspect that the solution is separating the ClosePrices file into separate files, one for each ticker, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for part 1, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069655/r-quantmod-storing-the-xts-object-returned-by-getsymbols/28534246#28534246). Your method won't work for index symbols like `^GSPC` or in general any symbol starting with special characters (due to the automatic assignment).

as for part 3, once you fetched all your symbols and stored them into `myList` as described in the link above, try the following to loop through your list and export elements of the list to your working directory:

```
require(quantmod)

#Vector of symbols to fetch prices for
symbols <- c('MSFT','SBUX','GOOGL')

#Initialize a list to store the fetched prices
myList <- list()

#Loop through symbols, fetch prices, and store in myList
myList <-lapply(symbols, function(x) {getSymbols(x,auto.assign=FALSE)} )

#Housekeeping
names(myList) <- symbols

#Export to seperate files
quiet <- lapply(1:length(myList), function(x){    #looping through all elements of your list
  write.csv(myList[[x]],     #accessing the xth element of your list
            paste0(names(myList)[x],'.csv'),   #naming the exported element
            row.names=index(myList[[x]])   #include dates in the export
  )  #close write.csv
}  #close function
)  #close lapply
```

EDIT: Combined the two posts as per the first comment.

Comment: I seem to be missing something I ran the code in the link through the myList section, but no dice when I apply the code above. Any chance you could post entire process in one fell swoop for easier review/analysis? Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the answer. give it a shot and if you get any errors please post it.

Comment: Yes, that works fine now. Thanks. But to go back to my original question, how would modify the code so that that the price data is saved as separate files--three data sets in the case of your example above. As currently written, the output is a single list object.

Comment: Well the most efficient way in my mind is to store them in a list so you can access them conveniently by subsetting the list. So for example if you need Microsoft you would just do `myList[['MSFT']]`. Is there a reason why you wanna have them stored in separate objects? It's attainable by implementing another `for` loop but I just don't see a reason why you would wanna do that.

Comment: Now that you mention it,.subsetting when required is probably the way to go. Thanks!