# Storing the xts object returned by getSymbols

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm trying to collect mutual fund performance data via open and close prices from quantmod.  I have scraped a list of 5000 some funds and am trying to loop through and get one open and close price for each fund.  I'm having difficulty calling the xts object yielded by `getSymbols()` as it is called invisibly into the environment.  Since the object is stored as its ticker name, I tried calling it by its ticker name.

Code so far:

```
## loop thru list and use quantmod to calculate performance from 1/2/14 to 12/31/14
for(i in 1:4881){
    ticker <- tickernames[i]
    getSymbols(ticker)
    Open <- ticker["2014-01-02",1]
    Close <- ticker["2014-12-31",4]

    performance2014[i] = (Open - Close)/Open
}
```

Is there a way I can call the object using `ls()`?

Comment: Try `help(getSymbols)` and look for `auto.assign`.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to set the `auto.assign` argument to `FALSE` in `getSymbols`. This way you deactivate `getSymbols` automatic assignment to the global environment.

Here's an example that should guide you through step by step:

```
require(quantmod)

#Vector of symbols to fetch prices for
symbols <- c('MSFT','SBUX','GOOGL')

#Initialize a list to store the fetched prices
myList <- list()

#Loop through symbols, fetch prices, and store in myList
myList <-lapply(symbols, function(x) {getSymbols(x,auto.assign=FALSE)} )

#Housekeeping
names(myList) <- symbols

#Access MSFT prices
myList[['MSFT']]

#Access SBUX prices
myList[['SBUX']]

#Access GOOGL prices
myList[['GOOGL']]
```

Hope this answered your question.